# Logs in Spring Security 4 with log4j and set MDC not working

Tags: multithreading, spring-security, slf4j, log4j2

In a web application environment with spring security 4, slf4j ( with log4j2 implementation) , there is a filter which is run at the top as soon as the request is received and always set the MDC parameters in thread as below

```
MDC.put("ServiceSequence", aSampleKey);
```

The log4j2 pattern layout has `%X{ServiceSequence}`. 
For every log line I see the correct `ServiceSequence` except the log which are generated from the custom implementation of `UserDetailsService`. In this custom implication the `%X{ServiceSequence}` is always empty.

When I debug the program, I found that may be the spring security thread is not the same thread which I set the MDC for. Is it correct ?!

How can I set a thread context in the filter and make sure that I have it in every where? Or can I configure the spring security to copy the thread parameters to its new thread context ?!

Comment: The order of filters?